# How to merge a branch to another branch in GIT?

Tags: git, branch

Let me explain the problem in detail.

I have a main git branch on which I created a new side branch bug10101010, now I wan't to merge the bug10101010 to main. So far everything is good.
Now I have a different branch of the same product, named legacy. I wan't to merge the bug10101010 to the legacy branch in GIT.

Any ideas?

I can't just merge it directly, as the branch bug10101010 is spin off from the main branch and in the legacy I need only the diff between the branch bug10101010 and its parent branch.

Comment: @Priyank: I agree, patch is simpler. But the method I describe is not complex. It illustrates also the ease with which you can clone a repo and make any Git operation you want, provided you are not pushing from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to do. Git saves merge history, and if you "cherrypick" and point at a commit in bug10101010 as a parent (indicating you have done a merge) Git will assume that all commits before that (back to the point where they split) as been merged as well. Giving you problems when you want to do a "real" merge.

On the other hand you can just manually generate a patch from that (and only that) specific commit. But that will also give you problems when you later do the "real" merge, since it tries to apply your manually handled commit twice.

But then again, since one branch is named "Legacy" I suspect that you dont plan to do that real merge anyway, in which case youre pretty much free to do it anyway you please.

Heres an [interesting blog post on the topic](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/merge_history.html).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful link.

So,what is your recommendation, and how to do the above.

Or let me rephrase the question: I need the ability to create bug specific transactions that are always merged to main, but needs the ability to replay these transactions on other branches at will.

Comment: What do you mean with "always merged to main"? A specific bug branch should only need to be merged back to the main branch once. If my general answer, coupled with the blog link and general git documentation, doesnt get you anywhere you might consider updating your original question detailing the specific workflow you aim for a bit more. I might be able to help then.

Comment: The questions is the same, branch bug10101010 is merged to the main, as all bug fixes must be present in the main branch. But how would you merge the specific changes in the done in branch bug10101010 with respect to its parent to the legacy branch.
As you are suggesting manually generate a patch and apply the same, but by doing that I am losing the ability to track that this changes come from this branch.

Comment: So the bug branch is branched from the legacy branch which itself is branched from the main? And now the bug branch should be merged back into main and then removed (since the purpose of the bug branch, fix bug, is fulfilled)?

Comment: The bug branch is branched from the main and not from legacy as there can be legacy 1.0.3, legacy 2.0.3, etc.
The idea of the bug branch is to create a transaction, the same as you create a patch manually.

Comment: Is there any special reasons, then, why you dont simply use patches? Is it for the lack of tracking capability? The idea behind a branch is generally that its created with a specific idea in mind, which is then implemented, after which the branch is merged back into main and then removed. I still think you try to use branches in a way theyre not meant to be used, as described in the link.

Answer (score 6):

You should use **`git rebase --onto`** here, and specify a range.
(see [`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using `rebase --onto`.

).

Of course, this would move your `bug10` branch on top of the `legacy` branch, which is not what you want/need.

So, one workaround would be to **do that rebase in a cloned repo, then merge that 'enhanced' `legacy` branch** (the one in the clone repo, with the `bug10` modifications on top of it) **to the local and current `legacy` branch** (the one you want to modify, while leaving `bug10` alone).

Now:

- this involves an extra repo (which can lead to disk space limitation)
- all in all, this is fairly equivalent to define a patch and apply it to `legacy` branch, so the other answers (patch) are valid (and simpler).
- the only advantage I see in this method is the opportunity to define a legacy environment in which you rebase what you want (like the `bug10` commits), before pushing only that branch `legacy` to your original repo (you would not push `bug10`, since its history would have been entirely rewritten!)

I just wanted to see if it works, so... Let's test that approach.
(Git1.6.5.1, on a old XP SP2, with a Powershell 1.0 session because of the [`Start-Transcript` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347721.aspx))

---

```
PS D:\> mkdir git
PS D:\> cd git
PS D:\git> mkdir tests
PS D:\git> cd tests
PS D:\git\tests> git init mainRepo
```

<sup>I like how I do not have anymore to make the git repo directory first, then type in it `git init`! [Since 1.6.5](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.5.txt):</sup>

> "`git init`" learned to `mkdir`/`chdir` into a directory when given an extra argument (i.e. "`git init this`").

<sup>This is GREAT!</sup>

Let's create 3 files, for 3 different purposes.
(For the sake of example, I will keep the file modifications separate per branch: no conflict during merge or rebase here.)

```
PS D:\git\tests> cd mainRepo
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo mainFile > mainFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo contentToBeFixed > toBeFixedFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo legacyContent > legacy.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git add -A
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -m "first commit"
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo firstMainEvol >> mainFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "first evol, for making 1.0"
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git tag -m "1.0 legacy content" 1.0
```

At this point, a `git log --graph --oneline --branches` returns:

```
* b68c1f5 first evol, for making 1.0
* 93f9f7c first commit
```

Let's build a `legacy`branch

```
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git co -b legacy
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo aFirstLegacyEvol >> legacy.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "a first legacy evolution"
```

We return to master, make another commit, which we will tag "2.0" (a release which will need some bug-fixing!)

```
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git co -b master
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git co master
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo aMainEvol >> mainFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "a main evol"
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo aSecondMainEvolFor2.0 >> mainFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "a second evol for 2.0"
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git tag -m "main 2.0 before bugfix" 2.0
```

We have:

```
* e727105 a second evol for 2.0
* 473d44e a main evol
| * dbcc7aa a first legacy evolution
|/
* b68c1f5 first evol, for making 1.0
* 93f9f7c first commit
```

Now we do a `bug10` bug-fixing branch:

```
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git co -b bug10
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo aFirstBug10Fix >> toBeFixedFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "a first bug10 fix"
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo aSecondBug10Fix >> toBeFixedFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "a second bug10 fix"
```

Let's add a final commit on the main branch

```
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git co master
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> echo anotherMainEvol >> mainFile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> git ci -a -m "another main evol"
```

Final state of our main repo:

```
* 55aac85 another main evol
| * 47e6ee1 a second bug10 fix
| * 8183707 a first bug10 fix
|/
* e727105 a second evol for 2.0
* 473d44e a main evol
| * dbcc7aa a first legacy evolution
|/
* b68c1f5 first evol, for making 1.0
* 93f9f7c first commit
```

At this stage, I will not make any further manipulation in mainRepo. I will only clone it to make some tests. If those fails, I can always get back to this repo and clone it again.

The first clone is actually mandatory, in order to perform our `git rebase --onto`

```
PS D:\git\tests\mainRepo> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests> git clone mainRepo rebaseRepo
PS D:\git\tests> cd rebaseRepo
```

We need two of the mainRepo branches in our cloned repo:

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git co -b bug10 origin/bug10
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git co -b legacy origin/legacy
```

**Let's rebase only bug10 (that is all commits after `2.0` tag up to `HEAD` of `bug10` branch)**:

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git co bug10
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git rebase --onto legacy 2.0
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: a first bug10 fix
Applying: a second bug10 fix
```

At this point `bug10` has been replayed on top of `legacy` **without all the other intermediate commits**.
We can now fast-forward `HEAD`of `legacy` to the top of the replayed `bug10` branch.

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git co legacy
Switched to branch 'legacy'
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> git merge bug10
Updating dbcc7aa..cf02bfc
Fast forward
 toBeFixedFile.txt |  Bin 38 -> 104 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

The content follow what we need:

- We do have all the legacy content:

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> type legacy.txt
legacyContent
aFirstLegacyEvol
```

- the content for the `main` branch is there only up to `1.0` tag (root for `legacy` branch), and **not any further**.

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> type mainFile.txt
mainFile
firstMainEvol
```

- and the `bug10` fixes are here:

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> type toBeFixedFile.txt
contentToBeFixed
aFirstBug10Fix
aSecondBug10Fix
```

That's it.
The idea is to to pull that 'enhanced' `legacy` branch in your original repo, which will still have its `bug10` unchanged (i.e. still starting from the `2.0` tag, and not replayed anywhere like we did on the `rebaseRepo`.
In this cloned repo, I track the `origin/legacy` branch, in order to merge on it the `legacy` branch of *another* remote source: the `rebaseRepo`.

```
PS D:\git\tests\rebaseRepo> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests> git clone mainRepo finalRepo
PS D:\git\tests> cd finalRepo

PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git co -b legacy origin/legacy
```

In this original repo (I only cloned it to not mess with the state of the mainRepo, in case I had some other experiments to do), I will declare `rebaseRepo` as a remote, and fetch its branches.

```
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git remote add rebasedRepo D:/git/tests/rebaseRepo
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> type D:\git\tests\finalRepo\.git\config
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = D:/git/tests/mainRepo
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "legacy"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/legacy
[remote "rebasedRepo"]
    url = D:/git/tests/rebaseRepo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/rebasedRepo/*

PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git fetch rebasedRepo
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From D:/git/tests/rebaseRepo
 * [new branch]      bug10      -> rebasedRepo/bug10
 * [new branch]      legacy     -> rebasedRepo/legacy
 * [new branch]      master     -> rebasedRepo/master
```

We can now update `legacy` without touching to `bug10`:

```
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git merge rebasedRepo/legacy
Updating dbcc7aa..4919b68
Fast forward
 toBeFixedFile.txt |  Bin 38 -> 104 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

You can repeat the process as many time as you want, whenever new `bug10` commits need to be replayed on top of an old `legacy` branch, without including all the intermediate commits.

Comment: I must say WoW!, but I am almost confused with the steps and its seems so complex to a newbie like me. I just go with manual patch way. git diff label label~ and then git apply, that seems easy for me.

Comment: At the end of this the master branch does not have the bug10 changes, right? I thought what the original poster (and I) wanted was to have bug10 in both the legacy and the master branch?

Comment: @huggie the OP did mention "I wan't", which, more than four years ago, I must have interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and then [git-apply](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html)?

Comment: how would you track then, that what you merged came from the branch bug10101010, which is basically just a transaction.
Also its not straight forward. I need the ability to specify just the branch-name and merge the changes.

Comment: The idea is too create a bug transactions (using small branches) and replay those transactions, effortlessly to anywhere (any branch). Creating a patch and merging the same, can be done in CVS/SVN also, then no use of moving to Git.

Comment: If the branch is a transaction, should after its purpose is finished, the branch effectively be removed, and thus simply logging that the patch is a fix for bugXXXXXXXXX be enough? Since the point of the transaction is to encapsulate the changes, the sum total of which then can just be tracked as an aggregate?