# Tagging steps for a tutorial?

Tags: git

I want to write a python and django tutorial and combine this with hands on exercises. The tutorial will consist of a list of tasks to do: Step 1, Step 2, Step 2.2.... It would be awesome if i can create a git repository for the exercise and tag the commits which represent a step in my tutorial.
If this is done, i am able to jump to any point in my tutorial, go the commit in the exercise and can compare the steps and even skip some steps.

My first thought was: easy. 
My second thought: not so easy or a lot of work.

For example: I can tag the repository with "1", "2", "2.2" after everything is done and i can find all the steps in my git history, tag them and write down the sha1 for every step. So far so good. But now i want to change something in my first step. This change is important and i want to have this change in every step after this. So i have to re-tag each step again because i have to update all my tags and will get new sha1s.

In a normal software development scenario, i would just apply the "hotfix" to a couple of stable branches and tag new versions. Here, i want to change existing tags.... and maybe 50 or more of them.

Is there any way for me now to do this without going insane with tagging and retagging everything by hand? I can write software to do the tagging job but maybe something already exists of what i am not aware of?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a branch for every version, instead of using tags. If, for example "4" bases ond what you did in "2", you create a branch from "2" and commit your changes in "4".

Here's an example repository:

[image: Example git repository]

Steps to get this structure:

- Created `1` from master
- Switched to `1`
- Deleted master `git branch -d master`
- Created and switched to `2`.  (`git checkout -b 2`)
- Created and switched to `2.1`.
- Switched back to `2`
- Created and switched to `3`

Comment: i do think this is the correct way to do this with git tools but i think i will write a little piece of code to automate some of this.

Comment: Of course you can automate `git checkout -b` with a little shell script: For example `./create.sh 2 4` would create a new branch feom 2.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried exactly this for a tutorial of mine with 5 stages. It's annoying to maintain and people have to understand git properly just to learn the subject which was, as I discovered, not necessarily true with a large audience. I'd recommend you go with a dumber approach and duplicate the code into multiple directories, one per stage.